# Creating Hierarchy Parent has Same Child as Another

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a hierarchy in power bi and running into the error "Each value in 'Master'[ChildID] must have the same value in 'Master'[ParentID]. The value 'Drawing 1' has multiple values" when attempting to create a path using the table below.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANIny.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyzyD.png)

To my understanding, you cannot have different parents with the same child in the hierarchy since at the second level, it will not know which parent to point to. Is there a way to create a data tree/path that allows me to create this? I have also attached a diagram of the tree that I want to create.

[Desired Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyubE.png)

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/09/using-dax-to-handle-multiple-parent-hierarchies/

Answer (score 0):

Your datatable design is wrong for this hierarchy. You either build a query to get this design or you change your datatable. This is how your table have to look like:

```
Material       Drawing         MWR
 Mat1           Draw1          Mwr1
 Mat1           Draw2          Mwr1
 Mat2           Draw4          Mwr1
 Mat2           Draw3          Mwr7
 Mat1           Draw1          Mwr5
 Mat1           Draw3          Mwr2
 Mat2           Draw4          Mwr6
 Mat2           Draw3          Mwr6
```

If you have your data like this you just need to drag and drop (at the fields pane) `Drawing` into `Material` and `MWR` also into `Material` (just on the last place) and you have your hierarchy.